# What is the best workflow for Matlab Simulink + Git?

Tags: git, matlab, merge, bitbucket, simulink

We are maintaining a Simulink model with many subsystems. A number of teams contribute to the core model. Likewise, they sync their customized models with the core model. Currently, it's done by checking detailed update notes, following guidelines and lots of copying/pasting. We want to do it in a proper way.

We are using a bitbucket server for our GIT repository. Fork+PR doesn't work since conflicts can only be resolved,

- using Model Comparison Tool (obviously not possible on Bitbucket)
- between branches (using Model Comparison Tool is cumbersome when there are two repositories, it requires selecting old and new models/scripts manually)

**Here is our workaround for contributions to upstream repository:**

Every contributor,

- creates their own branch in their own fork
- does their contribution to common subsystems
- creates a PR

Then new branch is pulled by the upstream repository. The new branch and untouched main branch merged using Model Comparison Tool by the upstream repository owner.

**For updates from upstream repository to forked ones:**

- main branch in forked repo synced with upstream repo
- main branch and custom branch merged using Model Comparison Tool by the forked repo owner.

Can anybody suggest a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "better"? Which part of the problem you described are you looking to make "better"? I am not familiar with Simulink enough to say whether this is possible with .slx files, but when I needed to track the revisions of .fig or .mlapp files (which are binary), I used to export them as code and only check-in the output code to the VCS. Other than that, it appears that the workflow you describe is along the lines of what [the Simulink documentation on the topic](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/check-for-modifications.html) advocates. [1/2]

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for an external diff tool for .slx files, such as the ones listed [here](https://www.diffplug.com/features/simulink#comparison). [2/2]

Comment: I was searching for a workflow with fewer manual steps involved. Since documentation does not offer a better way to compare models, I think our proposed workflow is a good start. About the external diff tools you suggested all members have required licenses but I was not aware of such tools. Thanks!